# How to write Sqlite DataBase in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite

I am using this code for creating SQlite Database in Qt.
Now I have 2 questions: First how can I add new record in table , and second how can I check the table exist?

```
bool createConnection()
{
    QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("SQLITE");
    db.setHostName("Server");
    db.setDatabaseName("Message.DB");
    if (!db.open()) {
        QMessageBox::critical(0, QObject::tr("Database Error"),
                db.lastError().text());
        return false;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should be able to work:

```
QSqlDatabase database = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
database.setDatabaseName("Message.DB");
if(database.open() == false) {
    // ... <- Error handling
    return false;
}

QSqlQuery sqlQuery(database);
bool inserted = sqlQuery.exec("INSERT INTO my_table (col1, col2) VALUES (\'one\', \'two\')");
if(inserted == false) {
    // ... <- Error handling
}
```

Not sure how to check if table exists but to create a table if it does not already exist you can do:

```
bool created = sqlQuery.exec("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS my_table(<column info>);");
```

Answer (score 0):

You should also create query which will create not empty database and use correct name of variable(in your code you use dbConnection firstly and after that - db.